# Modifying Marlin Extruder code to use 28byj-48 motor

Tags: marlin, stepper

I'm currently working on a project to convert an old 3D printer to a 2D powder dispenser. I'm using a Ramps 1.4 + Arduino Mega, and I'm trying to modify the extruder code in Marlin. I've printed a check plate and attached it to a 28byj-48 stepper motor.

The idea is to trigger the 28byj-48 motor to move a few steps in one direction to open the check plate on a "begin extrude" command (allowing the powder to flow through via gravity) and to close the check plate on a "stop extruding command".

However, I'm getting a little bit overwhelmed with the Marlin code, and would love any help making these changes or even figuring out which files I would need to look at to do this.

I've already done the [hack on the stepper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sY1Y_BJ-fTQ) to make it work with the Ramps board, but haven't touched any of the code yet. Right now vanilla Marlin is running fine with my hardware, and I'm able to move the x and y axes fine.

** If you're interested, this is the inspiration for the project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXceYzhCWcs

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thanks! Hoping I can figure this out - any thoughts?

Comment: I'm a newbie to this stuff. Anything beyond throwing PLA into my printer and slicing something from Thingiverse and I'm left out ;-)

Comment: The process you describe sounds very inaccurate. Preferably you should use an auger to dispense the powder. But, if you want to follow the path you started, you might want to look into controlling a servo from Marlin.